# Why do the finitely generated subsheaves of a sheaf form a directed system?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories

Suppose we have a ringed space $(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ with sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules $\mathcal{F}$. Let $I$ be an indexing set and suppose we have a collection of subsets $U_{i} \subseteq X$ along with a collection of sections $s_{i} \in \mathcal{F}(U_{i})$ both indexed by $I$. The subsheaf generated by the family $\{ s_{i} \}_{i \in I}$ is defined to be the image of the canonical morphism
$$
\phi: \bigoplus_{i} \mathcal{O}_{U_{i}} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F},
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_{U_{i}}$ denotes the extension by zero of the restriction to $U_{i}$.

> Why is the collection of all finitely generated subsheaves a directed system?

I feel like this is a stupid question, because it seems so blatantly intuitively obvious that if $J \subseteq I$ is a subset (where both $J$ and $I$ are finite), then the subsheaf generated by the set $J$ will be a subsheaf of the subsheaf generated by the set $I$, but I can't see how to prove this using the formalism above.

In particular, if I have
\begin{align}
\phi: \bigoplus_{i} \mathcal{O}_{U_{i}} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \\
\psi: \bigoplus_{j} \mathcal{O}_{U_{j}} \longrightarrow \mathcal{F}
\end{align}
how do I construct a monomorphism $\text{im} (\psi) \rightarrow \text{im}(\phi)$? Is there another way to see immediately that the resulting collection is actually a directed system?

Comment: Because the sum of two of them is also one of them.

Comment: In any abelian category you have $\operatorname{im}(f\circ g)\subset\operatorname{im}(f)$ (maybe you can try to prove this in the category of sheaves). Now you can apply this to your morphisms $\phi$ and $\psi$. Notice that $\psi=\phi\circ i$ where $i$ is the inclusion $\bigoplus_j\mathcal{O}_{U_i}\rightarrow\bigoplus_i\mathcal{O}_{U_i}$.

Comment: @Roland thank you, that is precisely the kind of general fact I was looking for to make it work. In fact I had basically reduced it to that fact but wasn't able to convince myself the fact was true. I'll give it another shot, thanks!